# Adding inApp purchase in an update of an Application

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I am going to launch an Application on AppStore. It will have two versions, original version and updated version. 1 - 2 weeks later I will post the original version, I want to update the binary such that now few items that were earlier unlocked are now locked and available for inApp purchase. 
However I don't want the user who had downloaded the original version and now only updated it, to have those items locked. Only those who download the app for the first time after Updated version is launched should get the items locked.

I am thinking to implement this. I will create the inApp purchase for the updated version even before original version is launched. and get the key. Now somehow get this key to be stored in the device when user downloads the original version. But I am not sure if this the right way to do it and how will this key be preserved across devices

Also the inApp will show in the iTunes page should not show inApp purchase with original version.

Comment: create a key in the NSUserDefaults for users who download the first version. With the second version, check if that key exists - if so don't lock the items, otherwise lock the items.

Comment: @kaan thanks. I was concerned if this preserve across devices ? Like a user downloads the application on his iPhone and after few days on his iPad will NSUserDefault get synced via apple ID ?

Comment: If you want to sync the NSUserDeafults between different devices, you need to use iCloud the do this work.

Comment: @kJuly ... does that mean if the user does not use iClould setting on his device it will not be possible to do this ?

Comment: @ila mum..yes, as far as I know. You can build your own server to store the data for user & sync it when user login.